# Check if there are duplicate number in different arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am new to this language, I am trying to create a 2d arrays, then loop through it and get the column (I got this part), I have put the number in the column inside arraylists. But I wonder if there is a way to check through these arraylists to see if there is duplicate number in them. For ex:

```
row0:   9-8-7-6-5
row1:   4-3-2-1-0
row2:   1-9-8-4-3
```

So if there is duplicate number in column2: 8 3 9 and column1: 9 4 1. The duplicate number is 9. So print the number and the column numbers out.

```java
ArrayList<Integer> column0 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> column1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> column2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> column3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> column4 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

int[][] arrays = new int[][]{
        {top1, top2, top3, top4, top5},
        {mid1, mid2, mid3, mid4, mid5},
        {bot1, bot2, bot3, bot4, bot5}};

for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    column0.add(arrays[i][0]);
    column1.add(arrays[i][1]);
    column2.add(arrays[i][2]);
    column3.add(arrays[i][3]);
    column4.add(arrays[i][4]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to check the duplicates, you have to use another data structure to keep track of the values that you have already seen. Set will be a perfect candidate because you can look up any element in O(1) complexity.

Your code should look something like this

```
Set<Integer> seen;
List<List<Integer>> lists;
public void add(int index, int value) {
    if(!set.contains(value) {
        lists.get(index).add(value);
    }
}
```

Here, index is the row in your 2D list and value is the actual value you want to insert.